# How is weak convergence in L^1(0,T; BV(\Omega)) defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I have a question regarding a proof. Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T > 0$.

How is  the following convergence defined?
\begin{equation}
 U_n \longrightarrow u \text{          weakly in } L^1(0,T; BV(\Omega)),
\end{equation}
where $BV(\Omega)$ is the space of functions with bounded variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always: It means
$$
F(U_n) \to F(u)
$$
for all $F$ in the (topological) dual space of
$L^1(0,T;BV(\Omega))$.

However, the dual space of $L^1(0,T;BV(\Omega))$ seems to be quite ugly, therefore, this might not be what you intended.